# How to display an alert when user shake the iPhone?(This should be work even user is not using the app)

Tags: iphone, ios, core-motion

I want to fire a method(Display alert) in my app when user is shaking the iphone.This should be work even if user is not using the app.How can I do it ?

Answer (score 3):

If your app isn't running in the foreground you can't access the accelerometer.  You can't do what you're planning to do with iOS, at least not unless you jailbreak.